# Risks of running on single byte character app on a MBCS OS

Tags: c++, mfc, internationalization, mbcs

I have an MFC application where the Character Set is "Not Set".  What are the risks associated with running this application on a OS that has a Multi Byte Character Set code page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Character Set: Not Set" option defines neither `_MBCS` nor `_UNICODE`. That means that you're using the *A series of functions. Those *will* return MBCS strings, even when `_MBCS` is not defined.

If `_MBCS` doesn't affect the strings returned from the *A functions, then what does it do? It maps some `<tchar.h>` `tcs*` functions to their `mbs*` versions, instead of the `str*` or `wcs*` variants. E.g. without `_MBCS`, `_tcsrev` maps to `strrev`, not `_mbsrev`.

Therefore, you may not be able to reverse the multi-byte strings you receive from the OS, or edit them otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The risks are:

1) If you use non-English texts, and the user enters, say, Russian, some Russian characters that are not mapped to MBCS or require a Charset layer, will be retrieved as '?'

2) You need to inform the customer that the App. accepts English-only and no guarantee the App, when entering non-English characters, would accept or retrieve non-English texts correctly.

3) Any texts with foreign language characters may lead to unwanted or undesired conversion of accents and diacritics to something else.